# I would like selenium to judge some text on a page, return true, no false

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like selenium to judge some text on a page, return true, no false

For example, I create a function to determine whether a certain paragraph of text appears on a web page. If this text appears, it returns 'true', otherwise it returns 'flase'. But I don't know how to use 'selenium' to write this, the following The code is what I tried to write.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
n=1
driver = 
webdriver.Chrome('F:\pythonjiaoben\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('this is my game url')
def is_text(a):
    try:
       s=driver.find_element_by_link_text(a)
       return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False

elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("地狱之门[永恒]")
elem.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
while(n>0):
    if is_text("您点击的太快了，请等会再刷新！"):
        elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("返回游戏")
        elem.click()
        continue
    if is_text("进入世界"):
        elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("进入世界")
        elem.click()
        continue
    break
```

It shows these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jiaoben.py", line 24, in 
    elem.find_element_by_partial_link_text("进入世界")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 273, in find_element_by_partial_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 653, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. What do you mean by *judge some text on a page, return true*? selenium doesn't check anything, it perfume actions. What are the "mistakes" you are referring to? post the stack trace if you have any and tell us what is wrong.

Comment: @Guy 
I am from China. My English is poor. I hope to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: My proposals:
Get content (text) of the element with Selenium. Then with python, make your assertions.

Pseudo code:
text_to_search = "abc"
text=driver.find_element_by_class_name("current-stage").getText("my text")
 if text_to_search in text: 
    continue
else:
    break